# How to access to object properties by string with another object

Tags: javascript, object

I need to access to object properties by string with another object
In php you can reach that like if array $b = 't';$a->$b; is the same as $a->t

```
var obj = {
    title : 'spider'
}

var hero = {
    spider : 'is a hero'
}

console.log( hero.spider );//works fine
console.log( hero.obj.title );//i need the same result, from variable (obj)
```

how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(hero[obj.title])
```

I think this should work.